# I can log in to the wordpress admin but when I go to the site pages, why does 'localhost redirected you too many times' come up?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

My client's live wordpress website went down when the host forced an upgrade to PHP 7. I downloaded his site and db locally and tried to merge it with a newer Wordpress version that can handle PHP 7 but I can only access the admin area.

I keep on getting the 'localhost redirected you too many times' message.

I've tried deactivating plugins, adding this code

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://localhost:80');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://localhost:80');
```

I looked at my `access.log` and it says `301 20`

how can I stop it from redirecting?

Answer (score 0):

I was just working on this myself today. The Home and Site URL should be locating the area that all of the wordpress files are in.

For example:

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://example.com/pathToWordPress');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com/pathToWordPress');
```

You also need to give the www user access to read those files. Depending on which operating system you're using its different for each one.

I was using Ubuntu earlier today and I had to give them access to read by entering this in my command line:

`chmod 755 www-data:www-data /var/www/example.com/public_html/wp-content`

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm using Windows, and it can access the files, I am able to insert echo commands up until  `require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/template-loader.php' );` in `wp-blog-header.php`, in which the redirect loop seems to be happening

Comment: Do you have error reporting on in your wp-config? Also just because you can edit/read from your computer doesn't mean that a user on the web can. Which is essentially how you're treating yourself when you try and access the site.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove .htaccess file in your website directory, then just go to Settings - Permalinks and click Save Changes button.